# Restrict Excecution Access

Tags: php

Lets say we have multiple domains in the same hosting account.
The tree is like:
home->website1
home->website2
home->website3

The problem is that website3 or website2 can contain a php or js file which include a php or js file from website1.

First example, website3 or website 2 can contain a php file like:

```
<?php include "../website1/index.php"; ?>
```

Second example, website3 or website 2 can contain a js file like:

```
<script src="../website1/index.php" />
```

How can we restrict execution access from website3 and website2 access the website1 from all languages, is there any code for root htaccess to disable access to website1 from other folders?

Comment: Why not just move the `index.php` files into the root directories where they are supposed to have access?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for htaccess configs. That's more of a ServerFault question than a question for here (server configs).

Comment: This could likely be easily solved in the configuration file of your webserver, but unfortunately you aren't saying which one you are using (Apache? Nginx? IIS?).

Answer (score 0):

> How can we restrict execution access from website3 and website2 access the website1 from all languages?

There is no universal way to do such thing which would work for each and every language.

As per your requests in your question:

> First example, website3 or website 2 can contain a php file like:
>
> ```
> <?php include "../website1/index.php"; ?>
> ```

You may want to take a look at the [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) PHP configuration directive, it will allow you to prevent PHP scripts from opening any file outside of the given directories.

Be aware however that, as this setting does its job well, it may have side effects if your websites needs to access external files for legitimate purposes. As with any security enforcement system, you must know what you do and thoroughly test your changes before applying them on production.

> Second example, website3 or website 2 can contain a js file like:
>
> ```
> <script src="../website1/index.php" />
> ```

This one doesn't seem valid, mainly for two reasons:

- JavaScript is executed on the visitor's browser, not on the server, and the browser will most likely not have access to the `../website1/` directory.
- PHP and JavaScript are unrelated, you cannot execute PHP code in JavaScript.

Maybe you thought about something like:

```
<script src="http://www.website1.com/myscript.js" />
```

Here a page from website3 or website2 is relying on a script hosted and publicly shared by website1, there is no real way to prevent this (checking the `referer` HTTP header may limit this, but definitively not block it).

This does neither leak any information nor open any security weakness though, since the `myscript.js` is already publicly shared by website1.